# Can the clerics archetype Crusader ability legion blessing be used with wands?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, archetype

For the purpose of magic items specifically wands, using a charge from the wand to cast the spell still causes you to be the caster of the spell, so in the case of held touch spells you cant just keep building them up. The important part from this is that you count as the caster despite your ability scores, caster level, and other effects are not cared about, only that the spell is cast with whatever modifiers it was made with.

Now, as you are the caster of the spell, is it possible to combine it with the cleric's archetype [Crusader](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo---cleric-archetypes/crusader) and its 8th level ability legion blessing?

Legions Blessing

> At 8th level, a crusader gains the ability to confer beneficial spells quickly to a large group of allies. As a full-round action, the crusader may confer the effects of a single harmless spell with a range of touch to a number of creatures equal to half her cleric level. The spell’s range remains touch, so all intended recipients must be within the crusader’s reach when the spell is cast. Using the legion’s blessing expends the prepared spell, but it also requires the crusader to sacrifice another prepared spell three levels higher, as when spontaneously using a cure or inflict spell. The higher-level spell is not cast but is simply lost, its magical energy used to power the legion’s blessing.

A specific example of what I want to do is have a wand of endure elements, and "channel" this spell using the crusader ability to my allies. This means I dont have to have endure elements prepared.

Answer (score 2):

**No, activating Legions Blessing is a Full Round action itself, not spellcasting in the traditional sense.** It expends two spell slots on the Cleric; you cannot substitute other objects for the spells that are expended. See this portion of the ability:

> ... As a full-round action, the crusader **may confer the effects** of a single harmless spell with a range of touch to a number of creatures equal to half her cleric level (...) Using the legion’s blessing expends the prepared spell, but it also requires the crusader to sacrifice another prepared spell three levels higher...

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

Legions Blessing

> At 8th level, a crusader gains the ability to confer beneficial spells quickly to a large group of allies. As a full-round action, the crusader may confer the effects of a single harmless spell with a range of touch to a number of creatures equal to half her cleric level. The spell’s range remains touch, so all intended recipients must be within the crusader’s reach when the spell is cast. **Using the legion’s blessing expends the prepared spell**, but it also requires the crusader to sacrifice another prepared spell three levels higher, as when spontaneously using a cure or inflict spell. The higher-level spell is not cast but is simply lost, its magical energy used to power the legion’s blessing.

The spell in the wand is not a prepared spell, so legion's blessing may not enhance it. (A wand has charges, not prepared spells, and the text on activating a wand does not mention expending prepared spells.)